# Integrate MPGS session.js in Aurelia SPA

Tags: single-page-application, aurelia, mastercard

I am trying to integrate the MasterCard Payment Gateway services to a SPA using Aurelia.

I am trying to use the hosted checkout mechanism to integrate MPGS.

I am writing code in the attached event of the Aurelia viewmodel to load the session.js library and on load of the library adding another script element to initialize the session.

The attached method is listed below.

```
this.mpgsSessionScript = `if (self === top) { var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack"); antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack); } else { top.location = self.location; } PaymentSession.configure({ fields: { card: { number: "#card-number", securityCode: "#card-cvv", expiryMonth: "#card-expiry-month", expiryYear: "#card-expiry-year" } }, frameEmbeddingMitigation: ["javascript"], callbacks: { initialized: function(response) { console.log(response); }, formSessionUpdate: function(response) { } } }); function pay() { PaymentSession.updateSessionFromForm('card'); }`;

this.styleElement = document.createElement('style');
this.styleElement.setAttribute('id', "antiClickjack");
this.styleElement.innerText = "body{display:none !important;}";
document.head.appendChild(this.styleElement);

this.scriptElement = document.createElement('script');

this.scriptElement.src = this.sessionJs;
this.scriptElement.onload = () => {
    const innerScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    innerScriptElement.innerText = this.mpgsSessionScript;
    document.body.appendChild(innerScriptElement);
};
document.body.appendChild(this.scriptElement);
```

I can successfully run the code the and the script elements are added to DOM and also, the antiClickjack style gets removed, which indicates that the script element gets added.

But the issue is, the card number and the cvv elements are not getting enabled for input. If successfully initialized, the card number and the cvv elements should get enabled.

I do not see any errors in the console. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Two things I would check are: card/cv2 inputs are readonly, and the correct gateway is being pointed to (i.e. na [north america], eu [europe] etc)

Comment: @s1cart3r, thanks for the reply. But the issue was with the configuration object. It was configured wrong. The correct configuration was: 
fields: {
                cardNumber: "#card-number",
                securityCode: "#card-cvv",
                expiryMonth: "#card-expiry-month",
                expiryYear: "#card-expiry-year"
            },